# how i can call joomla module with ajax?

Tags: ajax, joomla

i create new joomla module
and i want call this module with ajax in easyblog component when client click on button
for this work i use com_ajax but this way dont help me 
please check my code 
my module name is mfk_following

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  SitePath= $(location).attr('hostname')+"/\analyze";
       $('body').on('click','span', function() {

            $.ajax({

   url: SitePath+"index.php?option=com_ajax&module=mfk_following&format=raw&authorid=" + 1,
   type: 'get',
   success: function(response){

                            alert(response); 
                          
                
      
  
                        }
                        
       
                    });
                    alert('check clicked');
                     });
    });
```

```html
 <div class="btn_follower" tabindex="<?php echo $user->userID; ?>" >
                <a  class="pluginButtonContainer" title="<?php echo $user->userID; ?>"  href="#"  >
  <span class="pluginButtonLabel" title="<?php echo $user->userID; ?>">
   <?php echo JText::_('Follower'); ?>
                    
   </span>
 
                </a>
                
                    </div>


 // in view.html.php
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
     $authorid = JRequest::getVar('authorid', 'authorID', '', 'int');
                echo $authorid;
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_mfk_following','default');

?>
```

i am not sure this url is true please help me

Comment: You can't call module from ajax.

Comment: You need to convert the whole module to a string. Then it is no different than any other string. I feel that the protostar template has a good example of this in how it renders models on the cpanel.